# Matlab "matrix dimensions must agree" when using function handle

Tags: matlab, debugging, matrix

I am getting the error "inner matrix dimensions must agree" in the code below

```
t = linspace(0,10,100);
x_exact = exp(-(t-4).^2); % exact solution
x_exact = x_exact';
lambda = randn(size(x_exact)); % diagonal values

A = diag(lambda); % diagonal matrix
y = A*x_exact; % exact data
delta = 1e-3*randn(size(y)); % noise
y_delta = y+delta; % noisy data

%% Define functional

% preallocate the memory
N_alpha = 3;
alpha = zeros(1,N_alpha);
resulting_x = cell(1,N_alpha);

alpha(1) = 1e-9;
alpha(N_alpha) = 1;

x = zeros(100,1);

for n = 1:N_alpha
    alpha(n) = alpha(1)+(n-1)*((alpha(N_alpha)-alpha(1))/(N_alpha-1));
    alphas = alpha(n);
    T = @(x) 1/2*norm(A*x-y_delta)^2+(alphas/2)*norm(x)^2; 
    resulting_x{n} = fminsearch(@(x) T(x),zeros(1,N_alpha));
end
```

specifically on the line `T = @(x) 1/2*norm(A*x-y_delta)^2+(alphas/2)*norm(x)^2;`. I have tried to change `*` to the pointwise product `.*` but then I get the error "inner matrix dimensions must agree".

`x` is supposed to be vector input which will be well defined when multiplied by the matrix `A`, but this function handle is causing some problems

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider what are you trying to minimise `T` with respect to. The initial conditions `x0` which you supply (in your case `zeros(1,N_alpha)` should be usable in place of `x` when your function is `T`. They are not, as `x` should be a 100-element column vector, not a 3 element row vector!

Using this will work:

```
resulting_x{n} = fminsearch(@(x) T(x),zeros(100,1));
```

But it seems perhaps you're confused about what `x` is, because you don't need to define it above the loop. Perhaps you meant to do

```
x0 = zeros(100,1);
for n = 1:N_alpha
    alpha(n) = alpha(1)+(n-1)*((alpha(N_alpha)-alpha(1))/(N_alpha-1));
    alphas = alpha(n);
    T = @(x) 1/2*norm(A*x-y_delta)^2+(alphas/2)*norm(x)^2; 
    resulting_x{n} = fminsearch(@(x) T(x), x0);
end
```

For more information, see the [`fminsearch` documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
@(x) 1/2*norm(A*x-y_delta)^2+(alphas/2)*norm(x)^2
```

tries to multiply matrix `A` by its input argument `x`. But your code sets up `A` as a 100 x 100 matrix, while the call to `fminsearch` tells it that the initial input to the function should be a 1 x 3 vector. That's why you correctly get the `Inner matrix dimensions must agree` error.

Your code is making one out of `A` and `x` the wrong size; you need to compare what the code is doing against the algorithm you're trying to implement to determine which.

Comment: The problem is that setting `N_alpha=100` produces the same error

Comment: So now you're trying to multiply a 100 x 100 matrix by a 1 x 100 row vector, which still won't work. If you change `A*x` to `A*x'` (i.e. transpose `x` to a column vector) then your code runs. You have to figure out whether that's the correct solution to implement your algorithm though.